# GD, libJPEG loaded, imagejpeg returns false

Tags: php, image, gd, jpeg

I'm having a strange behavior with PHP, GD, and libJPEG

Here is my phpinfo() for GD:

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version 8
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.44
WBMP Support    enabled
XBM Support enabled
```

This is what I'm doing :

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("/home/logo.jpg");
var_dump($img)
```

Result is false. Image exists, and is chmodded 777.

I'm running php 5.3.9, also make test FAILED on JPEG <-> png conversions and others JPEG operations.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**SOLUTION FOUND : remove --disable-rpath from ./configure. And now I'm going to take a gun and shot me in the head.**

Comment: If most of test cases failed, it is clearly something wrong with your libJPG library.

Comment: Any other people having trouble with libJPEG 8? Actually I got no problem on another server with libJPEG 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run

```
 $data = getimagesize("/home/logo.jpg");
 var_dump($data);
```

and make sure that the MIME TYPE of the image is image/jpeg

another reason might be that the path to the file is not true (maybe you need to remove the starting "/" and leave only `imagecreatefromjpeg("home/logo.jpg")`
[if the home directory is in the same level as your php file - than you should]

Comment: Returns : array(7) { [0]=> int(200) [1]=> int(200) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> string(24) "width="200" height="200"" ["bits"]=> int(8) ["channels"]=> int(3) ["mime"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } which is correct

Comment: @spacenick can you upload the image so we can loog deeper into the problem? another good option is to work with the Imagick library, that an Object oriented library for image handling with much better results than GD

Comment: Yah actually it doesn't seems to be image-related since it's actually not working with any image (I made a small upload/crop avatar script, and made the test with my logo.jpg image).

It's still pretty sick that it manages to get size etc but not opening it :/

Comment: maybe `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents("home/logo.jpg"));` will work. check if the `fopen` function is enabled in your system, otherwise `imagecreatefromjpeg` won't work